# If Worksheet is not shown at Macro Start, .find() is nothing

Tags: excel, vba

My Problem is for me very weird. I was searching and reading other VBA problems, which look like to me to my problem more equal. I don't know.

**use case:**
The macro should activate/select a sheet in a active workbook. Then find in that active worksheet a date/string. If its found it will save the range to an variable. In case the variable is nothing, then the macro should stop.

**problem:** If the sheet was not selected/activated by start of the macro, then the .find() is not working. Every Time I got a "nothing" back. If the worksheet was selected/activated by macro start (show on my monitor), then it works.

I checked the problem on a other PC as well. But it happens there as well...

```
    Dim rngFirst As Range
    Dim rngNext As Range
    Dim rngArea As Range
    Set rngArea = Range("A:Z")
    Dim defaultValue As Date, insertedDate As Date
    defaultValue = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")
    insertedDate = Application.InputBox(message, title, Format(defaultValue, "dd.mm.yyyy"), Type:=1)

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("mySheet").Activate
    Do
      If rngFirst Is Nothing Then
         Set rngFirst = rngArea.Find(What:=insertedDate, After:=rngArea(1))     'the problem start with this code line. What I got back is "Nothing"
         Set rngNext = rngFirst
         If rngNext Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "There was a problem with finding the meeting date. Please check!" + Chr(10) + "The Macro will end here."
            Exit Sub
         End If
      Else
         'Do something with what was found
         'find the next entry in the sheet
         Set rngNext = rngArea.Find(What:=insertedDate, After:=rngNext)
         If rngNext.Address = rngFirst.Address Then Exit Do
      End If
    Loop
```

Note: Unfortunatly I dont have Administrator on my working PC... But I think that don't make a diffrence.

Comment: `Set rngArea = Range("A:Z")` refers the active sheet and this happens **before activating the sheet you need**. In fact there is no need to activate the sheet in discussion. Try `Set rngArea = Sheets("mySheet").Range("A:Z")` and do not activate anything.

Comment: Thank you! I added the working code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved. It was a wrong thinking way...
The comment under my question explains the solution.

Here is the working code:

```
    Dim rngFirst As Range
    Dim rngNext As Range
    Dim rngArea As Range
    Set rngArea = Sheets("mySheet").Range("A:Z")       'added solution here
    Dim defaultValue As Date, insertedDate As Date
    defaultValue = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")
    insertedDate = Application.InputBox(message, title, Format(defaultValue, "dd.mm.yyyy"), Type:=1)

    Do
      If rngFirst Is Nothing Then
         Set rngFirst = rngArea.Find(What:=insertedDate, After:=rngArea(1))     'the problem start with this code line. What I got back is "Nothing"
         Set rngNext = rngFirst
         If rngNext Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "There was a problem with finding the meeting date. Please check!" + Chr(10) + "The Macro will end here."
            Exit Sub
         End If
      Else
         'Do something with what was found
         'find the next entry in the sheet
         Set rngNext = rngArea.Find(What:=insertedDate, After:=rngNext)
         If rngNext.Address = rngFirst.Address Then Exit Do
      End If
    Loop
```